# How to set DNS server to dns_get_record function?

Tags: php, dns

I'm studying http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php and there seems to be no option to set a custom DNS server. Are there any alternative function in PHP that can do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the PEAR's library Net_DNS2 : http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS2

You can specify which nameserver you want to query to.